# Validate a number and allow spaces

Tags: javascript, redux-form

I'm currently using redux form to validate some of my fields:

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
  }

  if (!values.details) {
    errors.details = 'Must declare'
  }

  if (!values.phone) {
    errors.phone = 'Required'
  } else if(!isNumeric(values.phone)) {
    errors.phone = 'Must ne a number'
  }

  if (!values.fax) {
    errors.fax = 'Required'
  } else if(!isNumeric(values.fax)) {
    errors.fax = 'Must ne a number'
  }

  return errors
}
```

My problem is that an entry of "9428 5977" gives a validation error due to the space in between. How can I fix my validation to allow this space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a RegExp to match your input.

```
function isNumeric(n) {
    return n && /^[0-9 ]+$/g.test(n);
}
```

According to your sample code that mentions a phone and fax, I believe that you do not want something like `-3.05E-08` to be valid even if this is a valid finite number.